# How should I set the JAVA_HOME environment variable on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, java-home

I know this question has been asked a lot before but i did read and i will show you what i got.

I will list the commands that i did in my **OS X Yosemite 10.10.1**

**java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

**java -fullversion**

```
 java full version "1.8.0_45-b14"
```

**which java**

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Java home variable is not set because when I do this: **echo $java_home** or **echo $JAVA_HOME** or **echo $Java_Home** i got nothing on the terminal.

when doing this: ls -l `which java`  i got this:

```
8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  74 Nov 12  2014 /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

**javac -version**

```
javac 1.8.0_45
```

**/usr/libexec/java_home**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

#### The solution that I think is correct after reading on internet is

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`" >> ~/.profile
```

but i am afraid to test it, that is why i am asking you, if that is correct or not and if not what should i do please?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are afraid to test, you can safely test this:

In your terminal session, input the following:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`"
```

This will print the following line:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Copy the above and paste it into your terminal window, then press enter key. and execute `java -version` to see it work correctly. If everything is okay, you can attach the code into your `.profile`:

But adding this line directly is better idea because you don't have to update `.profile` when you upgrade JDK.

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

Please refer to the man page for the [java_home](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html) tool. In short, it provides the appropriate path for JAVA_HOME for a normal installation on macOS

Comment: so are you saying that i just need to do this `export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`` and then the java home variable is okay setted ?

Comment: Yes. perhaps you want to read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html

Comment: I did your code, and now when I did this `echo $JAVA_HOME` I got this ` /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home` does that mean that the java home variable is setted correctly now please?

Comment: Run `java -version`. If it work okay, than the variable is set correctly.

Comment: by running java -version, i got this `java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)` so are we done please?

Comment: Yes. Try set invlid path to JAVA_HOME and try run `java` command and see what happen.

Comment: when i set java home to a non existing folder, i got error message that file deson't exist. then i tried echo java home and nothing happened. then i re set the java home to the correct folder and re run echo java home and  i got the correct path.

Comment: sorry for being panic, but we have finished right? now i can go on to continue installing things that need java home setted correctly?

Comment: Theres a command for discovering JAVA_HOME: https://confessionsofanagilecoach.blogspot.com/2019/12/setting-jdk-in-sts-4-on-macos.html