# JAVA_HOME libgdx error macOS Sierra

Tags: java, libgdx, jvm

I'm trying to generate a *libgdx* project using **"project generator"** but it shows this error:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

But I have installed the JAVA 1.8, using the terminal command it shows this:

```
$ java -version

java version "1.8.0_101"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)    
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

So how to setup the right jvm, someone have any suggestion or the solution to correct this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are using unix type operating system. If so do the following steps :

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`"
```

If it prints empty like below

```
JAVA_HOME=
```

then you should install java first from oracle site :
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html

If it prints like this :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then you should set your Java Home path like following way :

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

Please check this out. This link might give you lucid view to set Java Home to valid path.

[mac os how to set java home correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454505/mac-os-how-to-set-java-home-correctly-in-the-path)

Hope this knowledge sharing helps you. Thanks

Comment: not an explanation but finally found out why my JAVA_HOME was broken

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you type this command in terminal: echo $JAVA_HOME

If that is showing the older version of java, you will just need to update your JAVA_HOME settings.

Set JAVA_HOME using this command in Terminal: export JAVA_HOME= path to JDK

echo $JAVA_HOME on Terminal one more time to confirm the path was changed.

One other thing to keep in mind is sometimes, depending on the programs/projects, you could run into an issue between 32 and 64 bit versions. You might want to doublecheck you are using the right one.

Comment: It shows: ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directoryDone! and the **echo** shows: **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk**